# Dispatching cascading/dependent async requests in Flux/React

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I know this question has been asked more times in different flavours, but I didn’t find the "right" answer yet (maybe there just isn't one), so I’m looking for the "most Flux" one.

### Simple example:

- two components - `LoginForm` and `Information`
- user has to provide his/hers login information, submit the form and only after that he/she has right to "ask" for the information (this should be done automatically after login)
- Project structure along these lines:

  ```
  + actions
  |-- LoginAction
  |-- InfoAction
  + api
  |-- API
  + components
  |-- LoginForm
  |-- Information
  + stores
  |-- LoginStore
  |-- InfoStore
  ```

### Options:

1.

- `LoginForm._onSubmit()` calls `LoginAction.login()`
- `LoginAction.login()` calls `API.login()` with callbacks/promises and then in case of successful login it calls `InfoAction.requestInfo()`

2.

- `LoginForm._onSubmit()` calls `API.login()`
- if `API.login()` is succesful it calls `LoginAction.loginSuccess()` and:

  1. either `InfoAction.requestInfo()` which calls `API.requestInfo()`
  2. or `API.requestInfo()` which then calls `InfoAction.infoSuccess()`

3.

- `LoginForm._onSubmit()` calls `LoginAction.login()`
- `InfoStore` listens to `LOGIN_OK` action and it calls the `API.requestInfo()`
- `API.requestInfo()` calls `InfoAction.infoSuccess()` and that dispatches `INFO_OK` event with payload of the specific info that is going to be stored in `InfoStore`

(4.)

calling API/ServiceProvider or ActionCreators from `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` seems inherently bad. Not really a (good) option, but I’m putting it here for the sake of completeness.

### My evaluation:

1.
Good in the "old style" of callback/promise based JS, but doesn’t seem to be the Flux way, because we should avoid chaning actions. Just fire-and-forget.

2.
Breaks the "Flux diagram" slightly - components speak to API or ServiceProviders and not to ActionCreators directly. I'm not sure about whether this is good or bad. It seems to be "one-way" (good) and avoids circular requires (good). I personally prefer this option (specifically the 2.2. one)

3.
I personaly avoid this approach because it would mean Store talking to the API/ServiceProvider which breaks the “Flux diagram”, but again, I don’t know if it’s really bad (maybe it’s just me not being used to the Flux way of doing things). Even @fisherwebdev seems to be ok with this (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26637579/5053194), but is it really the best approach?

4.
Bad, bad, bad!

### Question

Which one is "the best" and/or is there any other "most Flux" option to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I recently watched an informative panel discussion that had, among others, two Facebook developers working on large-scale projects that used React/Flux. What struck me was that they took completely different approaches to the same problem -- and both seem perfectly good.

That said, here's how I'd handle it.

1. `LoginForm.onSubmit` calls `LoginAction.login`.
2. `LoginAction` calls `API.login` and, upon success, the Dispatcher launches an actionType of something like `Constants.LOGGED_IN` with data of the `user_id`
3. A `UserStore`, listening for `Constants.LOGGED_IN` makes a call to `API.userInfo`, passing the `user_id` that was in the dispatch. (Having a store get information directly from the API was one of the things one of the FB guys said they do routinely, reserving actions for updates and things of that nature.)
4. `UserStore` saves info into its `current_user` and emits a `CHANGE`
5. Affected components request an update to `UserStore`

Now, if you want to get trickier, you can have the store add arguments to its `emit`method, so that the affected components could pick up (a)the nature of what changed and (b)the actual data.

Hopefully, that's food for thought!

Comment: You might be right here, but personally I see this as breaking the "Flux flow diagram" - [Broken flux diagram](http://imgur.com/JNl9K0J)

Yes, FB devs seems to be ok with this (and they’re probably authority regarding this matter), but I'd like to have async code in one place only.

Second thing is that it could cause a “circular require”  - 1. API requires ActionCreator (AC) to call `AC.infoReceived()` 2. AC requires API to call `API.getNextInfo()` when Component says so.

Comment: Oh and I'm not necessarily talking about "User info" here - just some "general information" (weather report for next day, picture of a day) accessible only after login (behing paywall...). But that's just to clarify my train of thought, it shouldn't make difference in this case.

Comment: @TooManyQuestions, what did you end up with?