# Testing Flux store with async api using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jasmine, flux

I'm trying to test some very simple functionality with Flux store that on specific event call to service that make `http` request and return `Promise`, store looks like:

```
case UserActions.FETCH_USER_BY_ID:
   const userService = new UserService();
   userService.fetchUserById(action.id)
      then(user => {
        this.user = user;
        this.emit(USER_FETCH_COMPLETED);
      });
```

For the testing I'm using `Jasmine`, and my test case looks like:

```
it('should fetch user by id', () => {
  const userStore = require('../stores/userStore');
  const mockUser = {name: 'test', id: 123};
  spyOn(UserService.prototype, 'fetchUserById')
    .and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(mockUser));
  dispatchEvent();
  expect(userStore.user).toEqual(mockUser);
})
```

As expected this test if failed, because of asynchronous behavior of `Promise`, I'm understand the problem here but I'm can not find solution how to say to test wait until `Promise`  from `userService` resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using async calls inside the store. It can lead to an unpredictable state of the store. And probably you may have this error: [Flux Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581587/flux-dispatch-dispatch-cannot-dispatch-in-the-middle-of-a-dispatch).

Instead, your `userService` should `handleAction` with the user data, once the user fetched. And your store should update then the user data.

For example,

**User service:**

```
userService.fetchUserById = function(userId) {
  apiCall(userId).then(user => handleAction(UserActions.FETCH_USER_BY_ID, user));
}
```

**User store:**

```
   case UserActions.FETCH_USER_BY_ID:
     this.user = payload.data;
     this.emit(USER_FETCH_COMPLETED);
     break;
```

*Here is a good short article about fetching data with API and Flux:
https://medium.com/@tribou/flux-getting-data-from-an-api-b73b6478c015#.vei6eq5gt*

Then, you can write tests separately for your stores and services:

**Store Test:**

```
it('should fetch user by id', () => {
  const userStore = require('../stores/userStore');
  const mockUser = {name: 'test', id: 123};
  handleAction(UserActions.FETCH_USER_BY_ID, mockUser) 
  expect(userStore.user).toEqual(mockUser);
})
```

**Service Test:**

```
it('should fetch user by id', (done) => {
  const userService = require('../service/userService');
  // userService.fetchUserById(userId);
  // here you can add spyOn http service that you are using in the service
  // and mock the response from that service
  // and then validate that `handleAction` has been triggered
})
```